# Special characters in kvoptions (like \\)

Tags: kvoptions

I try to write a little package for my personal use. For this I use `kvoptions`. Now I have to give a string to one of the options which contains `\\` but this fails with: `undefined control sequence. \let \reserved@e`.

My texfile looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[myoption={Street\\City}]{mypackage}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{some name}
\opening{Dear ...}
\closing{Regards ...}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And the content of the .sty-file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
    family=mypackage
    ,prefix=mypackage@
}
\DeclareStringOption[]{myoption}[]
\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*\relax
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mypackage@myoption} %just for example
```

In reality I do more than just that with `myoption` but I need it to accept `\\` in the string. This is the only problem. As long as I don't use `\\` in the strings everything works fine. I can use a default for the option like this:

```
\DeclareStringOption[Other street\\Other city]{myoption}
```

Inside of the .sty but the moment I want to enter another value for `myoption` containing `\\` it fails. How is it possible to allow such characters in the options?

EDIT: added the `\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions`

Comment: Your package misses `\ProcessLocalKeyvalOptions*`, but that's not the solution

Comment: Oh, just forget that in the MWE... But thanks, I'll edit it :)

Comment: really latex doesn't support this (`\\ ` dies in the package loading code before kvoptions can see it.) You'd have to load a package that redefined `\usepackage` before you used an option in this way

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's too bad. But thanks for the clarification. Do you by any chance know any package that does that or can pinpoint me in the right direction?

Comment: kvoptions ought to but I just tried loading it earlier with no effect, there are other packages that define key=value package option handling (I forget which:-) or just put `\let\\\relax` before the package load (and put it back afterwards)

Comment: Should have thought of the `\let\\\relax` myself. Thanks a lot, it works now! You might put this as an answer so I can accept it as one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ^^ You have mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to load a package that redefines `\usepackage` to make this safe *before* the `\usepackage call that uses the option. Unfortunately just loading`kvoptions` earlier doesn't seem to work. There are other packages that define key=value package option handling (I forget which:-) or just put

```
\let\savednl=\\
\let\\=\relax
```

before the package load and put it back afterwards with

```
\let\\=\savednl
```

then it will be safe during the package option handling, but back to normal by the time you use the option value.